# jqgrid customformatter for link theme not visible

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jqgrid

Good day - 
I am using jqGrid (4.4.4) with jquery ui 1.10.0

I have set up using a custom formamtter to provide a simple link using

```
return "<a href='#'  onclick=\"openProlianceWindowAnchor('" + urlLink + "','" + rowObject.DocumentGuid + "'); return false;\" >" + cellvalue +"</a>";
```

While the link is workign just fine- the Text on the link gets washed out and is not visible because the background color and link color are nearly identical.

It doesnt seem to matter which theme i use the anchor text always gets washed out.

[image]

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding a `style` attribute to get around this?

E.g.

```
    return "<a href='#' style="color:black;" onclick=\"openProlianceWindowAnchor('" + urlLink + "','" + rowObject.DocumentGuid + "'); return false;\" >" + cellvalue +"</a>"; 
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: i know i can do that - but that distracts from the point of using Themes -

Comment: ok it was just a suggestion. Something is clearly overriding the css is your theme, I would suggest looking at it in a web inspector to see if the color is being inherited from somewhere else. If not then you could try adding `!important` to your theme styling so it takes precedence over all other styles.

Comment: i am only using the jquery ui theme and the jqgrid css

Answer (score 0):

In custom formatter function add a class `ui-state-default a` like given below

```
 return "<a href='#'  class="ui-state-default a" onclick=\"openProlianceWindowAnchor('" + urlLink + "','" + rowObject.DocumentGuid + "'); return false;\" >" + cellvalue +"</a>";
```

In case you want to add button instead of link you can use classes given below

```
ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only
```

These are jquery css classes so will be changed as per the theme you select

UPDATED:
If you dont want the link/button you can use the below code

```
return "<a href='#'  class=".ui-widget-content a" onclick=\"openProlianceWindowAnchor('" + urlLink + "','" + rowObject.DocumentGuid + "'); return false;\" >" + cellvalue +"</a>";
```

And if you dont wish to show the underline in the link use the below code

```
return "<a href='#'  class="ui-button .ui-widget-content a" onclick=\"openProlianceWindowAnchor('" + urlLink + "','" + rowObject.DocumentGuid + "'); return false;\" >" + cellvalue +"</a>";
```

Comment: Thanks Kris for the suggestion but that doesnt work either. see [link](http://nutshells.info/temp/jqgridAnchor.png)  with the results.

Comment: I thought you want a button/link styling as per your selected theme. See the updated answer

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Kris - none of those suggestions worked.  What I was attempting to get was simply a normal underlined text that matched the other values in the other columns (in this case a white background with black text) that matches the theme.  Thanks again for the suggestions.  Not sure why the anchor tags are getting fubared up - must be an oversite somewhere.

Comment: Are you sure you do not have other css files imported in your project ? just check your stylesheet files used in your project